# I need to access a position in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to have these methods in my code this is a code for class I'm just so lost I can't remember how to do this.

But let's continue to enrich our Notebook class with the following methods

- `addNote()` will add an individual note to the ArrayList
- `deleteNote()` will delete a note using its position in the ArrayList
- `getNoteNumber()` will get the position of a note based on its value, e.g., in what position is note "Buy milk"?
- `getNote()` will get the note text for a given position
- `setNote()` will set (update) the note text for a given position

---

```
public void addNote(String note)
{
    notes.add(note);
}
public void deleteNote(int index)
{
    notes.remove(index);
}
public void getNoteNumber(String note)
{
    for(int i=1; i<(notes.size()); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(notes.get(i));
    }
}
public void getNote(String note)
{

}
```

I'm looking for any kind of advice i can find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public void addNote(String note)
{
    notes.add(note);
}
public void deleteNote(int index)
{
    if(index < notes.size())
         notes.remove(index);
}
public int getNoteNumber(String note)
{
    for(int i=0; i<(notes.size()); i++)
    {
        if(notes.get(i).equals(note))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  //Note does not exist

}
public String getNote(int index)
{
     if(index < notes.size())
     return notes.get(i);
}

public void setNote(int position, String text)
{
    if(position < notes.size())
         notes.set(position,text);

}
```